# Geoserver followline and offset together

Tags: gis, styling, geoserver, cartography, sld

I have problem with styling label of stream. Geoserver able create offset label of stream, but I can not find how create follow line with offset.

I try use informations from official documentary, but a did not find it.

I find some info, than offset and followline does not work together.

Sorry, my english grammar is really terible.

Thanx for answers

Comment: can you add the SLD you are trying to use and screen shots of what you see happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

followLine and perpendicularOffset cannot be used toghether, the existing code does not support such combination.
In the past it was due to the lack of a offset curve generator, now it is available but its use needs to be added into the label rendering code.

If you are interested in making that happen read here: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer